# Как заменить подсветку на подчеркивание в PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, highlighting

Можно ли в PyCharm заменить подсветку синтаксиса и скобок c выделения на подчеркивание? (Привык к подчеркиванию в Sublime и не могу найти эту настройку в PyCharm)

[image: Выделение в PyCharm]

[image: Подчеркивание в Sublime]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `Settings/Editor/Color Scheme/General`, в `Code/Matched brace`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Было:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Стало:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Еще можно поиграться с Foreground/Background

Comment: Большое спасибо — поиграться с Foreground/Background было то что надо)

Comment: @АнтонКопылов, пожалуйста :)